# Android app calculator exits on start

Tags: java, android, eclipse, calculator

I've been trying to write a simple BMI calculator as my first app. I was using an outdated tutorial to do so and was not the first to have a problem running my app (it just exits when I try to run it), but what others sugested didn't seem to do the trick for me. I have no idea what's wrong so please help me fix this and point out what is wrong so I don't repeat my mistakes.

Here is my code:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

 int cm,kg,bmi,cm2;
 Button wsub10,wsub1,wadd1,wadd10,hsub10,hsub1,hadd1,hadd10,calcbmi;
 TextView displaybmi,h,w;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    cm = 170;
    cm2 = 0;
    kg = 60;
    bmi = 0;
    displaybmi = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextView04);
    h = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextView01);
    w = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextView03);

    Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),
            "fonts/lucida.ttf");
    //set typeface for all text
    TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView00);
    tv.setTypeface(tf);
    TextView tv1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextView01);
    tv1.setTypeface(tf);
    TextView tv2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextView02);
    tv2.setTypeface(tf);
    TextView tv3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextView03);
    tv3.setTypeface(tf);
    TextView tv4 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextView04);
    tv4.setTypeface(tf);
    TextView tv5 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextView05);
    tv5.setTypeface(tf);
    TextView tv6 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextView06);
    tv6.setTypeface(tf);
    TextView tv7 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextView07);
    tv7.setTypeface(tf);
    TextView tv8 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextView08);
    tv8.setTypeface(tf);
    TextView tv9 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextView09);
    tv9.setTypeface(tf);
    TextView tv10 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextView10);
    tv10.setTypeface(tf);
    TextView tv11 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextView11);
    tv11.setTypeface(tf);
    TextView tv12 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextView12);
    tv12.setTypeface(tf);

    //introduce buttons and what they do
    //weight buttons
    wsub10 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ImageView07);
    wsub10.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            kg -= 10;
            w.setText("" + kg);
        }
    });
    wsub1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ImageView08);
    wsub1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            kg -= 1;
            w.setText("" + kg);
        }
    });
    wadd1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ImageView09);
    wadd1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            kg += 1;
            w.setText("" + kg);
        }
    });
    wadd10 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ImageView10);
    wadd10.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            kg += 10;
            w.setText("" + kg);
        }
    });
    //height buttons
    hsub10 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
    hsub10.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            cm -= 10;
            h.setText("" + cm);
        }
    });
    hsub1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ImageView02);
    hsub1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            cm -= 1;
            w.setText("" + cm);
        }
    });
    hadd1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ImageView03);
    hadd1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            cm += 1;
            w.setText("" + cm);
        }
    });
    hadd10 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ImageView04);
    hadd10.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            cm += 10;
            w.setText("" + cm);
        }
    });
    //introduce button for bmi kg/cm^2
    calcbmi = (Button) findViewById(R.id.imageView3);
    calcbmi.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            cm2 = cm * cm;
            bmi = kg/cm2;
            displaybmi.setText("Your BMI is " + bmi);
        }
    });
}
```

}

Comment: Is your `onClick()` inside of your `onCreate()`? It looks that way, but it shouldn't be.

Comment: Can't you provide the exception/line number you get in LogCat?

Comment: post some logcat logs to see where is the issue and your activity_main.xml.  I assume it's somewhere calcbmi = (Button) findViewById(R.id.imageView3);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One error is that you are trying to cast an ImageView to a button

```
wsub10 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ImageView07);
```

should be

```
wsub10 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ImageView07);
```

Comment: Thank you, that seems to have been the biggest issue - the app starts now without trouble.

Answer (score 0):

You didnt provide stacktrace so, **`LET ME GUESS`**

My Attempt to Solve your problem :

1. You cast an `ImageView` to be a `Button` and yet in the `View` Heirarchy , `TextView` is the parent of `Button` while `ImageView`'s parent is `View`.
   View -> TextView -> Button

   **MEANWHILE**

   View -> ImageView
2. Post your logcat man!